# Django + tastypie + mongoengine + 500 error on saving model with backbone.js & backbone-tastypie.js

Tags: javascript, django, backbone.js, mongoengine, tastypie

This is the error I received when trying to do a simple save with a backbone model:

> {"error_message": "Could not save document (Mod on _id not allowed)", "traceback": "Traceback (most   recent call last):\n\n  File \"/Users/mbp/Projects/env/employii/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 195, in wrapper\n    response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/Users/mbp/Projects/env/employii/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 435, in dispatch_detail\n    return self.dispatch('detail', request, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/Users/mbp/Projects/env/employii/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie_mongoengine/resources.py\", line 390, in dispatch\n    return self._wrap_request(request, lambda: super(MongoEngineResource, self).dispatch(request_type, request, **kwargs))\n\n  File \"/Users/mbp/Projects/env/employii/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie_mongoengine/resources.py\", line 360, in _wrap_request\n    return fun()\n\n  File \"/Users/mbp/Projects/env/employii/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie_mongoengine/resources.py\", line 390, in \n    return self._wrap_request(request, lambda: super(MongoEngineResource, self).dispatch(request_type, request, **kwargs))\n\n  File \"/Users/mbp/Projects/env/employii/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 458, in dispatch\n    response = method(request, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/Users/mbp/Projects/env/employii/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 1408, in put_detail\n    updated_bundle = self.obj_update(bundle=bundle, **self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))\n\n  File \"/Users/mbp/Projects/env/employii/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie_mongoengine/resources.py\", line 561, in obj_update\n    return self.save(bundle, skip_errors=skip_errors)\n\n  File \"/Users/mbp/Projects/env/employii/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie_mongoengine/resources.py\", line 578, in save\n    return super(MongoEngineResource, self).save(bundle, skip_errors)\n\n  File \"/Users/mbp/Projects/env/employii/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 2230, in save\n    bundle.obj.save()\n\n  File \"../thecontractbox/apps/staff/models.py\", line 811, in save\n    return super(MHRBoxEmployee, self).save(*args, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/Users/mbp/Projects/env/employii/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/document.py\", line 294, in save\n    raise OperationError(message % unicode(err))\n\nOperationError: Could not save document (Mod on _id not allowed)\n"}

backbone code:

```
RAVE.Models.StaffModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot : '/m/api/v1/empployee',

    defaults: function() {
         return {
             active : true,
             visible : true
         };
    },
});

var StaffCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url : function(){
         return  '/m/api/v1/empployee/';
    },

    model: RAVE.Models.StaffModel,
});
```

this is the code that is called from a backbone view that breaks it:

```
if( this.model.get('has_access') ){
     this.model.save({'has_access' : false});
}
else{
     this.model.save({'has_access' : true});
}
```

Clearly this is caused because the model id is not allowed to be modified but tastypie is trying to modify. I am using the following versions:

```
django-tastypie==0.10.0
django-tastypie-mongoengine==0.4.2
mongoengine==0.8.4
Django==1.5
```

Comment: How is the _id changing?  Is it because its a string and not being converted to an ObjectId?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I find it hard to believe that this is the only way I can get it to work correctly, but currently this is a solution:

```
 if( this.model.get('has_access') ){
      this.model.save({'has_access' : false}, {patch : true});
 }
 else{
      this.model.save({'has_access' : true}, {patch : true});
 }
```

By passing {patch : true} with each save, it is only partially updating the model.

I am still waiting for any other solutions or for someone to confirm that my current fix is a correct way to do it.